# Return breaks my while loop when writing out rows from the database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, while-loop

I have a table with comments that contain users profilepicture, comment and userid. My code looks like this:

```
    while($Msg = $event->fetch())
    {   
        echo '

    <div class="activity" id="'.$Msg['id'].'">
    <div class="settings"><hr><hr><hr></div>
    <div class="actSwine"></div>
    <div class="act delete" id="delete">&times;<div class="abtSwine"></div><div class="abtbtn" id="deletewid">Radera</div></div>
    <div class="act" id="favo" onclick="alert(\'hello world\');">Favorisera<br><div class="abtSwine"></div><div class="abtbtn" id="favowid">Inl&auml;gget kommer att hamna under "Mina favoriter"</div></div>
    <div class="act" id="raport" onclick="alert(\'hello world\');">Anm&auml;l<br><div class="abtSwine"></div><div class="abtbtn" id="raportwid">Det h&auml;r inl&auml;gget &auml;r kr&auml;nkande.</div></div>
    <div id="clear"></div>
    <div class="activitylabel">
    <img src="'.$this->GetUserId($Msg['userid'], 'Profilepic').'" />
    <div class="activityname"><?php echo "@".$username." , " . $fname . " " . $lname ?></div>
    <div class="activitydomain"><?php echo $domain; ?></div>

    <div id="clear"></div>
    <p>
    '.$Msg['message'].'
    </p>
    </div>

    </div>  

    ';


    }
```

this returns only i 1 rows from the database. The functions that breaks my while loop is used here `"<img src="'.$this->GetUserId($Msg['userid'], 'Profilepic').'"/>"`. It returns a value given in the parameters, in this case the profilepicture of my user.

how can i do this differently without breaking the while loop? because as it has come to my understanding, a return pauses the while loop. This result in only printing out 1 comment from the database.

Comment: `<div class="activitydomain"><?php echo $domain; ?></div>` `Echo` within an `echo`? Maybe you should check this?

Comment: Yes, the echo shouldn't be here. This is because i copied my html and forgot to remove the echo. But im stuck with this problem, i want to solve it  before i move on.

Answer (score 0):

`return` from the function **doesn't break** anything here.

All you have here is some error which breaks page rendering.

Errors are in these two lines:

```
'<div class="activityname"><?php echo "@".$username." , " . $fname . " " . $lname ?></div>
<div class="activitydomain"><?php echo $domain; ?></div>'
```

As you already start `echo`ing, doing `echo` while `echo` is **invalid**. So - fix this lines.

Comment: I did, But it didn't solve my main problem. The while loop still stops after echoing out 1 comment from the database